# Directly (re)naming summarized columns with data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I want to check the proportions of certain categories inside columns of a data.table with respect to some grouping variable. A working chunk of code is attached that does just this:

```
require(data.table)

n_categories <- 5

dt <- data.table(categories = sample(paste("Category", 1:n_categories), 
                                     1000, 
                                     replace = TRUE), 
                 group_var = rep(1:10, 100))

dt[, lapply(1:n_categories, function(x) table(categories)[[x]]/.N), by = group_var]
```

The following output is produced:

```
    group_var   V1   V2   V3   V4   V5
 1:         1 0.22 0.19 0.18 0.24 0.17
 2:         2 0.17 0.23 0.18 0.23 0.19
 3:         3 0.17 0.22 0.21 0.17 0.23
 4:         4 0.17 0.17 0.24 0.19 0.23
 5:         5 0.26 0.19 0.16 0.19 0.20
 6:         6 0.14 0.19 0.24 0.21 0.22
 7:         7 0.12 0.14 0.28 0.30 0.16
 8:         8 0.13 0.19 0.19 0.17 0.32
 9:         9 0.23 0.26 0.24 0.17 0.10
10:        10 0.16 0.20 0.21 0.25 0.18
```

Now, I wonder if there is a way to modify the given code to directly assign column names ("proportion_category_1", "proportion_category_2", etc.) to the resulting data.table object other than assigning new column names in a new line of code.

The resulting data.table object should look something like this:

```
    group_var proportion_category_1 proportion_category_2 proportion_category_3 proportion_category_4 proportion_category_5
 1:         1                  0.22                  0.19                  0.18                  0.24                  0.17
 2:         2                  0.17                  0.23                  0.18                  0.23                  0.19
 3:         3                  0.17                  0.22                  0.21                  0.17                  0.23
 4:         4                  0.17                  0.17                  0.24                  0.19                  0.23
 5:         5                  0.26                  0.19                  0.16                  0.19                  0.20
 6:         6                  0.14                  0.19                  0.24                  0.21                  0.22
 7:         7                  0.12                  0.14                  0.28                  0.30                  0.16
 8:         8                  0.13                  0.19                  0.19                  0.17                  0.32
 9:         9                  0.23                  0.26                  0.24                  0.17                  0.10
10:        10                  0.16                  0.20                  0.21                  0.25                  0.18
```

The use of the `lapply` statement or some kind of routine that is able to group by an arbitrary number of categories is critical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this with `setNames`, which you just wrap around the `lapply` statement.

```
library(data.table)

dt[, setNames(
  lapply(1:n_categories, function(x)
    table(categories)[[x]] / .N),
  paste0("proportion_category_", 1:n_categories)
), by = group_var]
```

**Output**

```
   group_var proportion_category_1 proportion_category_2 proportion_category_3 proportion_category_4 proportion_category_5
 1:         1                  0.19                  0.19                  0.29                  0.20                  0.13
 2:         2                  0.26                  0.19                  0.19                  0.15                  0.21
 3:         3                  0.17                  0.16                  0.24                  0.22                  0.21
 4:         4                  0.19                  0.20                  0.21                  0.22                  0.18
 5:         5                  0.21                  0.19                  0.20                  0.21                  0.19
 6:         6                  0.24                  0.20                  0.11                  0.21                  0.24
 7:         7                  0.16                  0.29                  0.22                  0.12                  0.21
 8:         8                  0.14                  0.21                  0.23                  0.24                  0.18
 9:         9                  0.29                  0.22                  0.17                  0.16                  0.16
10:        10                  0.20                  0.27                  0.22                  0.19                  0.12
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way of solving your problem.

```
dt[, as.list(table(paste0("proportion_", sub(" ", "_", categories)))/.N), group_var]

#     group_var proportion_Category_1 proportion_Category_2 proportion_Category_3 proportion_Category_4 proportion_Category_5
#  1:         1                  0.13                  0.24                  0.21                  0.20                  0.22
#  2:         2                  0.25                  0.25                  0.14                  0.17                  0.19
#  3:         3                  0.27                  0.17                  0.16                  0.19                  0.21
#  4:         4                  0.26                  0.18                  0.20                  0.19                  0.17
#  5:         5                  0.17                  0.17                  0.22                  0.24                  0.20
#  6:         6                  0.18                  0.22                  0.20                  0.23                  0.17
#  7:         7                  0.20                  0.15                  0.27                  0.19                  0.19
#  8:         8                  0.19                  0.15                  0.21                  0.22                  0.23
#  9:         9                  0.19                  0.27                  0.18                  0.14                  0.22
# 10:        10                  0.20                  0.21                  0.19                  0.18                  0.22
```

Your example could work fine but in real data where all groups do not have the same number of distinct categories, you will get an error. This could be solved by creating a *factor* variable first and then tabulate it as follows:

```
dt[, .(cat = factor(paste0("proportion_", sub(" ", "_", categories))), group_var)
   ][, as.list(table(cat)/.N), group_var]
```